# VBA Send Email When Cell Value Changes

Tags: vba, excel

Need to find a way to offset the cell value in the email body. For whichever cell value triggers the email (meaning our target has been reached) I want to return the corresponding row value 12 columns to the left. You'll see in my code I've used Target.Offset(0, -12) but this is returning an error. I hope that makes sense.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim Target As Range    
    With Me
        Set Target = .Range("N1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
    End With

    If (Range("N45") = Range("F45")) Or (Range("N46") = Range("F46")) Or (Range("N47") = Range("F47")) Or (Range("N48") = Range("F48")) Or (Range("N50") = Range("F50")) Or (Range("N51") = Range("F51")) Or (Range("N52") = Range("F53")) Or (Range("N55") = Range("F55")) Or (Range("N56") = Range("F56")) Or (Range("N57") = Range("F57")) Or (Range("N58") = Range("F58")) Or (Range("N59") = Range("F59")) Or (Range("N61") = Range("F61")) Or (Range("N62") = Range("F62")) Or (Range("N63") = Range("F63")) Or (Range("N65") = Range("F65")) Or (Range("N66") = Range("F66")) Or (Range("N67") = Range("F67")) Or (Range("N68") = Range("F68")) Or (Range("N70") = Range("F70")) Or (Range("N71") = Range("F71")) Or (Range("N73") = Range("F73")) Or (Range("N74") = Range("F74")) Or (Range("N75") = Range("F75")) Or (Range("N76") = Range("F76")) Or (Range("N77") = Range("F77")) Or (Range("N79") = Range("F79")) Or (Range("N80") = Range("F80")) Or (Range("N81") = Range("F81")) Or (Range("N83") = Range("F83")) And _
            (Range("N84") = Range("F84")) Or (Range("N85") = Range("F85")) Or (Range("N87") = Range("F87")) Or (Range("N88") = Range("F88")) Or (Range("N89") = Range("F89")) Or (Range("N91") = Range("F91")) Or (Range("N92") = Range("F92")) Or (Range("N93") = Range("F93")) Or (Range("N95") = Range("F95")) Or (Range("N96") = Range("F96")) Or (Range("N97") = Range("F97")) Or (Range("N99") = Range("F99")) Or (Range("N100") = Range("F100")) Or (Range("N101") = Range("F101")) Or (Range("N103") = Range("F103")) Or (Range("N104") = Range("F104")) Or (Range("N105") = Range("F105")) Or (Range("N106") = Range("F106")) Or (Range("N108") = Range("F108")) Or (Range("N109") = Range("F109")) Or (Range("N110") = Range("F110")) Or (Range("N111") = Range("F111")) Or (Range("N113") = Range("F113")) Or (Range("N114") = Range("F114")) Or (Range("N115") = Range("F115")) Or (Range("N116") = Range("F116")) Or (Range("N117") = Range("F117")) Or (Range("N118") = Range("F118")) Or (Range("N121") = Range("F121")) And _
            (Range("N122") = Range("F122")) Or (Range("N123") = Range("F123")) Or (Range("N124") = Range("F124")) Or (Range("N125") = Range("F125")) Or (Range("N127") = Range("F127")) Or (Range("N128") = Range("F128")) Or (Range("N132") = Range("F132")) Or (Range("F134") = Range("N134")) Or (Range("N136") = Range("F136")) Or (Range("N138") = Range("F138")) Or (Range("N140") = Range("F140")) Or (Range("N142") = Range("F142")) And _
            (Range("N145") = Range("F145")) Or (Range("N146") = Range("F146")) Or (Range("N147") = Range("F147")) Or (Range("N148") = Range("F148")) Or (Range("N149") = Range("F149")) Or (Range("N150") = Range("F150")) Or (Range("N153") = Range("F153")) Or (Range("N154") = Range("F154")) Or (Range("N156") = Range("F156")) Or (Range("N157") = Range("F157")) Or (Range("N159") = Range("F159")) Or (Range("N160") = Range("F160")) Or (Range("N161") = Range("F161")) Or (Range("N162") = Range("F162")) Or (Range("N163") = Range("F163")) Or (Range("N164") = Range("F164")) Or (Range("N166") = Range("F166")) Or (Range("N167") = Range("F167")) Or (Range("N168") = Range("F168")) Or (Range("N169") = Range("F169")) Or (Range("N170") = Range("F170")) Or (Range("N171") = Range("F171")) Or (Range("N173") = Range("F173")) Or (Range("N174") = Range("F174")) Or (Range("N175") = Range("F175")) Or (Range("N176") = Range("F176")) Or (Range("N177") = Range("F177")) Or (Range("N178") = Range("F178")) And _
            (Range("N180") = Range("F180")) Or (Range("N182") = Range("F182")) Or (Range("N184") = Range("F184")) Or (Range("N185") = Range("F185")) Or (Range("N186") = Range("F186")) Or (Range("N187") = Range("F187")) Or (Range("N188") = Range("F188")) Or (Range("N189") = Range("F189")) Or (Range("N191") = Range("F191")) Or (Range("N192") = Range("F192")) Or (Range("N193") = Range("F193")) Or (Range("N195") = Range("F195")) Or (Range("N196") = Range("F196")) Or (Range("N197") = Range("F197")) Or (Range("N198") = Range("F198")) Or (Range("N199") = Range("F199")) Or (Range("N200") = Range("F200")) Or (Range("N201") = Range("F201")) Or (Range("N202") = Range("F202")) Or (Range("N203") = Range("F203")) Or (Range("N205") = Range("F205")) Or (Range("N206") = Range("F206")) Or (Range("N207") = Range("F207")) Or (Range("N208") = Range("F208")) Or (Range("N209") = Range("F209")) Or (Range("N210") = Range("F210")) Or (Range("N211") = Range("F211")) Or (Range("N212") = Range("F212")) And _
            (Range("N213") = Range("F213")) Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              Target.Offset(0, -12) & " has reached its target"

    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "email address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Target Reached"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here I have used the Worksheet_Change event and the Offset works fine.

```
Dim xRg As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Range("D1:D99"))
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If (Range("D7") > Range("E7")) Or (Range("D8") > Range("E8")) Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              xRg.Offset(0, -3) & " has reached its target"

    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "email address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Target Reached"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Send   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Target.Offset(0, -12)` in your `Mail_small_Text_Outlook` isn't defined. You can't set a variable in one subroutine and then use it in another unless that variable has been defined globally (outside of all subroutines and functions) or it is passed as a parameter to the subroutine.

Try instead:

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Target as Range)
```

Then calling that subroutine like:

```
Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Target)
```

With that you are passing the variable `Target` to the `Mail_small_Text_Outlook` subroutine.

---

Alternatively to set `Target` as a global variable so it is available to subroutines and functions in your VBAProject (I wouldn't in this case for reasons). You add to the top of your code (above your `worksheet_calculate` routine):

```
 Public Target as Range
```

Then remove your declaration of Target in your `worksheet_calculate` routine:

```
 'Dim Target As Range
```

Although, if you do this, then change the name of the variable since there are other built in subroutines like `Worksheet_Change()` that have `Target` as a built in variable and the scope is going to get all weird then.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried both methods but am still being asked to debug: "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              Target.Offset(0, -12) & " has reached its target"

Comment: Could it have something to do with the way I've set the Target Range?

Comment: If it's still having issues then take a look and see what Target.Row and Target.Column are set to when you hit debug. You are trying to step back 12 columns, and perhaps that is before column A.

Comment: I managed to get the offset to work using the Worksheet_Change event - I've added the code above. I thought this might help identify the issue.

Comment: I need to use Worksheet_Calculate as my range uses formulas. Worksheet_Change only seems to work if the cell value is changed manually.

Comment: I'm still curious what "Target" is set to by the time it hits that line. If it's multiple rows or columns then it would throw that error as you can only grab the ".value" of a single cell. Perhaps change it to `Target.Offset(,-12).Cells(1,1).value` to insure that only the top-left cell of whatever `Target` is set to is being pulled into that string concatenation.